# Only one simultaneous connection per user?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, connections

I'm currently experiencing some trouble, seemingly because my application refuses to connect to the database if there is already another connection open from the same user (but in a separate process).

Based on my observations, it doesn't seem to matter how many or few other users are connected, and `@@MAX_CONNECTIONS` is set to 0 (unlimited).

Is there any way such a *connections-per-user* limitation may have been defined on the database, and if so, how can I turn it off?

Here is my connection string:

```
[db]
sql=MS SQL
provider=SQLOLEDB.1
data source=foo\bar
connection=Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=foobar
```

As you might be able to discern from the above, we are connecting to the database using Microsoft OLE ADO. The application is an old VB6 legacy program.

By "refuses to connect" I mean that the method `Open` on the `ADODB.Connection` object fails.

Sadly, there is currently no log of the error output from this method in the production environment. I'm currently waiting for a patch to the application to be applied, to see if I can get extended information here.

Comment: I've never seen this controlled at the database level, almost always handled in the application. I have been in your situation where I've researched for days trying to figure it out, come to find out the app was limiting to one connection per userid/logonid.

Comment: Is there any LogOn trigger in your DB Server. Use this query to find that out. select
  t.name
, t.object_id
, t.is_disabled
, te.type_desc
 FROM master.sys.server_triggers t
   INNER JOIN master.sys.server_trigger_events te
     ON t.object_id = te.object_id

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way such a connections-per-user limitation may have been defined on the database, and if so, how can I turn it off?

You are using Microsoft SQL-Server. You can limit the Resources with the Resource Governor. Have a look at the Microsoft Documents. There you can see which options might be set and you should check. If there is a limitation, you may find it there.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor

Answer (score -2):

I think you may be able to turn MARS off to resolve this.  I had the same scenario with an application, and turning MARS off disallowed starting a new query before finishing the old one.

Try Adding this to your ConnString and resetting the connection:

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=false

Data Source=MSSQL; Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks; Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=false
```

[Link to article on MARS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx)